# Using regular expression to find repeating numbers

Tags: regex

In my database I have found a problem of people submitting phonenumbers that are just 10 numbers repeating (5555555555 or 7777777777) and I wanted to find a way to do a regular expression searching for any number repeating 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most beautiful regex, but it works

```
((?:1){10}|(?:2){10}|(?:3){10}|(?:4){10}|(?:5){10}|(?:6){10}|(?:7){10}|(?:8){10}|(?:9){10}|(?:0){10})
```

http://regex101.com/r/mK7iH6

Comment: This is a nicer regex than mine. however you don't need the ?: it works without it

Comment: @puser sure, but it's a non-capturing group, so no need to match it

Answer (score 1):

If your looking a mysql query, one method could be a single query with multiple ORs.

```
SELECT * from users WHERE phone_number='1111111111' OR phone_number='2222222222' OR phone_number='333333333' OR phone_number='4444444444' OR phone_number='5555555555' OR phone_number='666666666' OR phone_number='7777777777' OR phone_number='8888888888' OR phone_number='999999999'
```

If this issue is significant enough, you their are easy ways in javascript or php to validate phone entry.  The only problem is you will have users then creating fake phone numbers to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is best implemented without regular expressions, as a switch statement.

```
switch (number) {
        case 1111111111:  return true;
                 break;
        case 2222222222:  return true;
                 break;
        case 3333333333:  return true;
                 break;
        case 4444444444:  return true;
                 break;
        case 5555555555:  return true;
                 break;
        case 6666666666:  return true;
                 break;
        case 7777777777:  return true;
                 break;
        case 8888888888:  return true;
                 break;
        case 9999999999:  return true;
                 break;
        case 0000000000: return true;
                 break;
        default: return false;
                 break;
```

The reason for this is (to my knowledge) its faster, and the regex is pretty nasty too look at.

```
@"[(1111111111)(2222222222)(3333333333)(4444444444) etc (0000000000)]"
```